# Class pointer member pointing to that class: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have following header and source code that
declare a class with a member variable. The member variable is a smart pointer pointing to that class. When I try to assign a value to the pointer, the program fails to build with error: unresolved external symbol. Can sombody explain to me why this is the case?

```
Header.h

#pragma once
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

class myClass {
public:
    static shared_ptr<myClass> ptr;
};

class myClass2 : public myClass {

};

Class.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Header.h"
#include <utility>

int main()
{

    myClass instance1;
    myClass instance2;
    myClass2 instance3;

    instance2.ptr = make_shared<myClass>(instance3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message which you are getting i.e for which symbol it's saying undefined?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, ptr is a class variable rather than a instance variable since you define it to be static in header.h.  If you want to treat the ptr member as an instance member, you should remove the static declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a `static` member usually requires you to allocate storage outside the class for the `static` member. More info here: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Add a

```
shared_ptr<myClass> myClass::ptr;
```

to one of your cpp files to allocate storage.

But you are using the `static` member as an instance member, bringing into question whether on not you want a `static` member at all.